# Return whole group when filtering with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to return all the observations within a group if at least one of the group's observations meet a filtering criteria.

For example below, I would like only the groups "shoe" and "ship" and all of the values returned since both of those groups have at least one value under 50.

I tried using the group_by but it seems to only return observations where the filter criteria are met and not the whole group.

```
library(dplyr)

test <- data.frame('prod_id'= c("shoe", "shoe", "shoe", "shoe", "shoe", 
"shoe", "boat", "boat","boat","boat","boat","boat", "ship", "ship", 
 "ship", 
"ship", "ship", "ship"), 
       'seller_id'= c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a","g", "h", "r", 
"q", "b", "qe", "dj", "d3", "kk", "dn", "de"), 
       'Dich'= c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
       'price' = c(12, 200, 10, 4, 3, 4, 99, 55, 86, 88, 75, 64, 82, 
 21, 44, 34, 22, 33)
        )
```

Here is what I tried

```
test2 <- test%>%
         group_by(prod_id) %>%
         (filter = price < 50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `filter` with `any`

```
library(dplyr)

test%>%
   group_by(prod_id) %>%
   filter(any(price < 50))


#  prod_id seller_id  Dich price
#   <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 shoe    a             1    12
# 2 shoe    b             0   200
# 3 shoe    c             0    10
# 4 shoe    d             0     4
# 5 shoe    e             0     3
# 6 shoe    f             0     4
# 7 ship    qe            0    82
# 8 ship    dj            0    21
# 9 ship    d3            0    44
#10 ship    kk            0    34
#11 ship    dn            0    22
#12 ship    de            0    33
```

---

Or the base R approach using `ave`

```
test[with(test, ave(price < 50, prod_id, FUN = any)), ]
```

---

For completeness sake, one with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(test)[, if(any(price < 50)) .SD, prod_id]
```

Comment: Thanks! do you have a link to the original question/ answer? I couldn't find it when searching.

Comment: Oh nevermind I see the link at the top, thanks!